# webview.url not working on some android devices (in Titanium Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, android, url, webview

I am working on one titanium application.

And I am calling one `https://` URL into my application through `webview.url` property. On Moto g2 device,it will take some time to load that URL and after apprx.

30 sec webpage is displayed but for other devices it is not loading that URL & showing only blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve costs alot of resources from your device. I've noticed that loading a big image (around 15mb) in a webview slows down my app alot on Android. All UI animations / interactions are stuttering and slow on my HTC one m8 which is a decent phone. All this whilst the same code runs smooth on my iPhone 6S Plus.

What you can try is adding the following to `<application>` tag in your TiApp.xml:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:largeHeap="true"
```

My conclusion is that Android doesn't let you use the RAM you need for a smooth experience when handling large content in a webview.